# g++ error: specialization after instantiation (template class as friend)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, friend, g++4.8

Consider the following C++ code:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {};

class ConcreteSingleton : public Singleton<ConcreteSingleton> {
    template <class T>
    friend class Singleton;
};

int main() {}
```

`Singleton` shall be a **friend** of `ConcreteSingleton`:

It works with Microsoft's visual C++ compiler. But, I can't compile it with g++ 4.8.4. The error is:

> ```
>    error: specialization of ‘Singleton<ConcreteSingleton>’ after instantiation
>        template <class T> friend class Singleton;
> ```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Oh, it seems to be [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52625).

Comment: Works fine in Xcode (Apple LLVM 7.0 with C++14)

Comment: Fails to compile on g++ 5.2.0 as well. Works in clang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [GCC bug #52625](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52625).

Workaround stolen from its comments:

```
   template <class T>
   friend class ::Singleton;
//              ▲▲
```

I have verified that [your code doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0484b5b590e3f549), and [this code does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c143f309b42c36d).